# Display array item once(on click)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

Here is what i am trying to do..

1. On button click a random array item is displayed.
2. The array item can only be display once.

Currently i have set the code up as:

1. On click random array item is displayed.
2. Button click continues to loop through with no end.
3. Button click displays the item multiple times.

Here is a link to the code  http://codepen.io/fun/pen/aNedGQ?editors=1010

Help would be appreciated! =)

Below is the code, the same as the link above.

HTML

```
<div id ='display'> </div>
<div class ='button'>Next item</div>
```

JS

```
var items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

// Randomly on click display each item
// Only display each item once
// Stop when all items have been displayed

// Display to screen
var display = function(info) {
  var x = document.getElementById('display');
  x.innerHTML = info;
}
// Create random number
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length);
// Click handler 
$('.button').on('click', function() {
// Display random arr items to screen
  display(items[random]);
// Next item to be random
  random = (random + Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)) % items.length;
});
```

Comment: create an array and then append the displayed values to it so when everytime it wants to display the value so first check if it is already displayed by checking it first in the displayed values array if it isn't available there so then you can move forward and display it..!

Comment: If you want the solution is `JS` instead of `jQuery` ,I can post that??

Comment: And yes Array `splice()` is an interesting way to accomplish what you are really trying to do as : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can display random item and then remove it from array

```js
var items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
$('.button').click(function() {
  var rand = items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)];
  $('#display').text(rand);
  items.splice(items.indexOf(rand), 1);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='button'>Next item</div>
<div id='display'></div>
```

Comment: This works well and ends once there are no more items to display. Thank you